# Añadir elemento que contiene otros elementos hasta cierta cantidad, a otra lista y crear un nuevo elemento para contener el resto de los elementos

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, objeto

Me encuentro con este pequeño problema, les dejo parte del enunciado:

> Envasar(): Procesa todas las galletitas fabricadas embolsando aquellas que cumplen con los requisitos de calidad esperados. El proceso de envasado se encarga de crear las bolsas y va llenándolas hasta alcanzar o superar el peso esperado. Las bolsas llenas se estiban e inmediatamente se crea otra, todo hasta procesar hasta la última galletita. El último paso del proceso es informar los resultados del envasado. El método que imprime el informe está listo pero se requiere calcular el peso neto promedio real (el peso del contenido de cada bolsa, en promedio) entre todas las bolsas estibadas

Bueno como verán se trata de crear un Array que contiene "Galletitas" el mismo al llenarse de galletitas debe crear otro mismo elemento nuevo para volver llenarlo de "Galletitas", estoy trabado en la lógica de como crear un nuevo elemento una vez que este se halla llenado.

Cada bolsa se llena hasta a un máximo de 500 gramos, y cada galletita pesa aproximadamente de 10 gramos ( no todas pesan igual )

Les dejo lo que hice hasta ahora

```
public void envasar() {
    double grDesc = 0;
    Galletita galletitaAceptada = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.galletitasFabricadas.size(); i++) {
        if (this.galletitasFabricadas.get(i).getCalidad() == Calidad.ACEPTABLE
                || this.galletitasFabricadas.get(i).getCalidad() == Calidad.DESEADA) {
            
            for(Bolsa bolsa: this.bolsas) {
                embolsar(bolsa, this.galletitasFabricadas.get(i));
            }
            
            
        } else {
            grDesc += this.galletitasFabricadas.remove(i).getGramos();
        }
    }
    informarResultados(grDesc);
}
```

El problema esta en que no puedo y tampoco se me ocurre como crear la bolsa nueva y al mismo tiempo llenarla de galletitas, hasta que necesite crear otra repitiendo el proceso hasta terminar con el array de galletitas.

Comment: Pon tanto el enunciado como el código _como texto, con formato_. Además, especifica en la pregunta _cuál es el problema_. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Es Java o Javascript? Hay mucha diferencia entre ambos lenguajes.

Comment: Es java, ahora lo corrijo